# javascript text append

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

I dont know how to describe this but I'm sure you'll understand if you visit this link.
http://jsfiddle.net/pahnin/yN3xf/

I want to append text to a p element with javascript and I'm sucessful, but if the text contains a tag like `<font>` the tag is displayed as it is.

Should I add code to detect the html elements or it can be done any other means?
if I do add code which detect font tag how to add the tag back to the text??

Comment: don't use `font`, use `span`.

Comment: It works fine if you simply append it: http://jsfiddle.net/yN3xf/2/

Comment: my intention is to append each letter after some time period

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this. Once all the text has been written out, then you replace the whole html of `welcome` with the original text. It's not the best I admit.

http://jsfiddle.net/yN3xf/13/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var htmlcopied = $('.welcome').html();
    var textcopied = $('.welcome').text();
    $('.welcome').text('');

    function foobar(i) {
        if (i < textcopied.length) {
            $('.welcome').append(textcopied.charAt(i));
            setTimeout(function() {
                foobar(i + 1);
            }, 80);
        }
        else {
            $('.welcome').html(htmlcopied);
        }
    }
    foobar(0);
});
```

### UPDATE

This should give you the desired effect through different means. It has a div on top of the original text, and it slow reveals the text, which looks like it is being typed out.

**Example**

http://jsfiddle.net/guanome/LrbVy/

html

```
<div class="welcome">Hi, there <span class="hl">special text</span>, normal text
    <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.overlay').css('width', $('div.welcome').css('width'));
    $('.overlay').css('height', $('div.welcome').css('height') + 15);
    var origWidth = $('.overlay').css('width').replace(/px/g,'');
    foobar(origWidth);
});

function foobar(i) {
    if (i > -10) {
        $('.overlay').css('width', i);
        setTimeout(function() {
            foobar(i - 10);
        }, 80);
    }
}
```

css

```
.hl{
    color: red;     font-family: helvetica; 
    background: #efefef; 
    color: black; 
    padding: 2px 7px; 
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #CCCCCC; 
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #CCCCCC; 
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #CCCCCC;

}
div.welcome
{
    position: relative;
    width: 500px;
}
.overlay
{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: -3px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 25px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

### UPDATE 2

With this change, the overlay will be added dynamically to the welcome message, the width doesn't have to be set, and it will work with multiple lines easily.

http://jsfiddle.net/guanome/LrbVy/4/

html

```
<div class="welcome">Hi, there <span class="hl">special text</span>, normal text</div>
```

javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    showWelcome();
});

function foobar(i, overlay) {
    if (i > -10) {
        overlay.css('width', i);
        setTimeout(function() {
            foobar(i - 10, overlay);
        }, 80);
    }
    else {
        overlay.remove();
    }
}

function showWelcome() {
    var welcome = $('div.welcome');
    welcome.append('<div class="overlay"></div>');
    welcome.css('position', 'relative');
    var overlay = $('.overlay');

    overlay.css({
        'width': welcome.css('width'),
        'height': (welcome.outerHeight() + 5),
        'position': 'absolute',
        'right': '0',
        'top': '-3px',
        'background-color': '#FFF',
        'z-index': '10'
    });
    var origWidth = overlay.css('width').replace(/px/g, '');
    foobar(origWidth, overlay);
}
```

Comment: Thats the answer, Thnx, nice idea!

Comment: @pahnin I updated my answer, I think this will be what you are looking for.

Comment: +1. This is a neat idea, but works in a single line only, and requires the length of the sliding div to be known beforehand. See [my suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7890535/javascript-text-append/7892677#7892677) for a more flexible (and improvable, I don't know JQuery, actually) approach.

Comment: @XaviLópez the width doesn't have to be known and it can work with multiple lines with just a few changes. http://jsfiddle.net/guanome/LrbVy/3/

Answer (score 4):

You could simply replace `var textcopied = $('.welcome').html();` with `var textcopied = $('.welcome').text();` to extract the text without any HTML tags included. But then, of course, you won't get your tags back at all.

**Update:** A somewhat different approach uses jQuery animations to slide the entire title into view smoothly:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $title = $('.welcome');
    var twidth = $title.width();
    var theight = $title.height();
    $title.css({
        overflow: 'hidden',
        width: 0,
        whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
        height: theight
    }).animate({
        width: twidth 
    }, 5000); // milliseconds
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/yN3xf/16/

Comment: Thats what my basic problem is

Comment: The greater problem is that `.append` will only allow valid HTML. As your code stands, the only thing to do is somehow extract the HTML in advance and wrap it around *each character* as you append it again. Basically, as I see it, your entire approach is invalid.

Comment: @pahnin Try using jQuery `.animate` instead -- updated my answer.

Comment: still guanome's appraoch is better, I think its what I was looking for, I said I need to append after a certain time interval, animate fixes the time period of whole text, that means if I have larger text I have faster animation. Sorry.

Comment: @pahnin You could also compute the length of the `.text()` and multiply that by some constant to get your time interval. http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/yN3xf/18/

Comment: hmm.. but its simpler the other way, and adding font style after completing the animation looks better

Comment: moreover it looks like animation I just want to append which is successfully implemented in guanome's approach. I dont want to animate it I want to append it. Your appraoch is not constructive

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4507/discussion-between-pahnin-and-mblase75)

Answer (score 1):

You can also achieve this by iterating over the root element's `contents()`, and outputting individually each of the children nodes, one by one.

When treating each of `contents` elements, if it is a text node, it is enough to output all characters with a timeout. If it is not a text node, clone the node and append it to the target element. All characters inside it can be appended in the same way.

See it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/yN3xf/36/

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var $clonedContent = $('.welcome').clone();
    $('.welcome').textContent = '';
    $('.welcome').text('');

    treatContents(0, $clonedContent, $('.welcome'));

    function treatContents(num, container, target){
        var $originalNode = container.contents()[num];
        var $targetNode;
        if ($originalNode.nodeType == 3){
            $targetNode = target;
        }
        else{
            $targetNode = $(container.contents()[num]).clone(false, false).appendTo(target);
            $targetNode.text('');
        }
        $targetNode.textContent = '';
        writeCharacters($originalNode.textContent , 0, $targetNode, num, container, target);
    }

    function writeCharacters(origText, x, target, contNum, contCont, contTarg) {
        if(x<origText.length){
           target.append(origText.charAt(x));
            setTimeout(function() { writeCharacters(origText, x+1, target, contNum, contCont, contTarg); }, 80);
        }
        else{
            treatContents(contNum+1, contCont, contTarg);
        }
    }
});
```

This sample could be adapted to allow nested tags, for instance:

```
<p class="welcome">Hi, there <b>bold text <i>bold italic text</i></b>, normal text</p>
```

Comment: this is good too, although I dont want to read the tricky code, I liked this because I can use it anywhere I just need to add a class for my p tag unless the updated version of guanome's approach

Comment: An exception is being thrown on the last iteration of `$originalNode`, [I added a check](http://jsfiddle.net/guanome/yN3xf/38/) for `$originalNode` being undefined, which fixed it.

Comment: Thanks for the fix, @guanome, I knew something bad would happen with that `treatContents(contNum+1, ...` when there were no more children.

Comment: +1 for better multiline support. Mine would reveal all lines at the same time, your's would show one line at a time, nice.

Comment: @guanome well, that might be a bug, or a feature, depending on what is it expected to do ;-) http://jsfiddle.net/yN3xf/37/

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing:

```
$('.welcome').append(textcopied.charAt(i));
```

with:

```
textHTML += textcopied.charAt(i);
$('.welcome').html(textHTML);
```

And at the begening of the code, put this:

```
var textHTML  = '';
```

It works, but it doesn't look very good :P

Comment: my intention is to append each letter after some time period